# Hecl download ,but what next?

Tags: hecl

I have downloaded Helc from Hecl.org. I have also installed the SUN WTC. What next. Hecl is just in a zip file of 40meg with no extension. What do I do with it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you ought to post your questions to the mailing list, because there are different people there who are able to answer.  Second, what do you *want* to do with it?  Do you want to write programs for your mobile phone?  Then why not follow the tutorial:

http://www.hecl.org/docs/j2me.html#javame_tutorial

If that doesn't work or a step is causing you trouble, let us know on the mailing list and we'll help you figure it out.